# How to detect if an exception has been raised from a try block in python?

Tags: python, exception

For example:

```
class ExceptionMeta(type):
  def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    if exception_raised_from_try_block:
       do_something
    else:
       do_something_else

class TimeOutError(metaclass = ExceptionMeta):
  pass

try:
  raise TimeOutError
except Exception as e:
  pass
```

The actual problem is that I have a code block in which I am having a TimeOut error in the try - except block. Every time a TimeOut error is raised, I catch it in try - except block and issue retry for 5 times. This TimeOut error has an object which will collect the error traces in case the exception is raised so as to provide more context while debugging the issue. But every time the exception is raised in the try block, the call goes to call function and it ends up collecting the traces for that error which I dont want as I am just retrying again in the except block

Is there any way in python using inspection or some other module which can tell me that exception was raised from a try block?

Comment: what do you think happens in the except?

Comment: It seems like you are trying to filter out potentially uncaught exceptions. Is that correct? Can you explain further why you want to do that?

Comment: Looks like you want your exception to have a behavior if it is caught by a `try` block and another behavior if uncaught, but they are only a signal - exceptions should not have side effects.

Comment: I want to get it detected in the __call__ function if this has been raised from try block. Please advise on how to do that. When the exception will be raised, it will go to __call__ function as it is acting as a metaclass for it.

Comment: but why do you need such strange feature? Describe functionality you are trying fulfill, I've got feeling that this can be solved without this crazy concept.

Comment: @PauloScardine Yes, you got it right. Actually in my code, there are some additional steps which I want to do only as a side effect if exception is raised from try block, else I don't want to execute those steps. Could you suggest a way to do that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Looks like the question suffers from the A/B problem: @user2819403 has problem A, but instead of asking about problem A he is asking about his devised solution B. Please edit your question to show the original problem. The solution you are trying to implement is not idiomatic in Python.

Comment: @PauloScardine: The actual problem is that I have a code block in which I am having a TimeOut error in the try - except block. Every time a TimeOut error is raised, I catch it in try - except block and issue retry for 5 times. This TimeOut error has an object which will collect the error traces in case the exception is raised so as to provide more context while debugging the issue. But every time the exception is raised in the try block, the call goes to __call__ function and it ends up collecting the traces for that error which I dont want as I am just retrying again in the except block.

Comment: Are you using a retry decorator for the retry functionality?

Comment: It is an interesting problem and would make for a great question. We must stop using the comment system and edit the question in order to fulfill this potential.

Comment: @PauloScardine BTW we call it [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/) here.

Comment: @PauloScardine: Edited the problem. Do you have any suggestions for the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is retrying a block of code...

Suppose you have some code like:

```
import random

def do_something_unreliable(msg="we have landed"):
    if random.randint(0, 10) > 1:
        raise Exception("Timed out...")
    else:
        return "Houston, {0}.".format(msg)
```

You can retry 5 times by doing:

```
for attempt in range(1, 5):
    try:
        do_something_unreliable()
    except Exception:
        # print("timeout, trying again...")
        pass
    else:
        break
else:
    do_something_unreliable()
```

You can make it reusable by doing:

```
def retry(fn, args=None, kwargs=None, times=5, verbose=False, exceptions=None):
    if args is None:
        args = []
    if kwargs is None:
        kwargs = {}
    if exceptions is None:
        exceptions = (Exception,)
    for attempt in range(1, times):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except exceptions as e:
            if verbose:
                print("Got exception {0}({1}), retrying...".format(
                         e.__class__.__name__, e))
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then you can write:

```
>>> retry(do_something_unreliable, verbose=True)
Got exception Exception(Timed out...), retrying...
Got exception Exception(Timed out...), retrying...
Got exception Exception(Timed out...), retrying...
'Houston, we have landed.'

>>> retry(do_something_unreliable, ['we are lucky'], verbose=True)
Got exception Exception(Timed out...), retrying...
Got exception Exception(Timed out...), retrying...
'Houston, we are lucky.'
```

You can also take a look at the `retrying` decorator:

> [Retrying](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) is an Apache 2.0
>   licensed general-purpose retrying library, written in Python, to
>   simplify the task of adding retry behavior to just about anything.